# How to save value generated by for loop inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, variables

I have the following code

```
function getNumberWithCommas(number) {
  return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}

   var price = [
  6599, 7659, 899, 569, 899, 279, 219, 1797, 3999, 2769, 599, 1349, 2149, 219,
  219, 519, 2499, 2949, 5149, 7689, 15999,
];
    
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      var productPrice = document.createElement("span");
      productPrice.className = "price";
      productPrice.setAttribute("id", `price-id-${i}`);
      var calculatedPrice = price[i] * quantities[i];
      productPrice.textContent = `R$ ${getNumberWithCommas(calculatedPrice)},00`;
  precoTotalDiv.appendChild(productPrice);
        var totalPrice = [];
        totalPrice.push(calculatedPrice);
        console.log(totalPrice);
    }
```

It dynamically creates prices for products based on their quantity in the cart and their price. I would like to save these values (calculatedPrice) inside an array so I can get a total price (sum of all the prices) at the bottom of the cart.

It is adding calculatedPrice to totalPrice[], but it only adds one value, the length of the array remains one. Once I click another product, calculatedPrice gets overwritten with another products price.
I would like to get a sum of all the prices generated, not the sum of only one product.

Comment: So put `array.push(calculatedPrice)` in the loop.

Comment: Why do you need an array to calculate the total? Just put `total += calculatedPrice` in the loop.

Comment: BTW, you're never appending the span to the DOM.

Comment: I tried, but the saved value gets reset to another product's price.

Comment: Show what you tried. We can't guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Just updated the post with what I tried. Hopefully it is clear enough.

Comment: You create a new array on each iteration...

Comment: I've noticed that this is a frequent beginner mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just move `let totalPrice = []` to outside of the loop:

Because when you put totalPrice inside the loop and it will be reset value on each loop

```
    var totalPrice = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      var productPrice = document.createElement("span");
      productPrice.className = "price";
      productPrice.setAttribute("id", `price-id-${i}`);
      var calculatedPrice = price[i] * quantities[i];
      productPrice.textContent = `R$ ${getNumberWithCommas(calculatedPrice)},00`;
      precoTotalDiv.appendChild(productPrice);
      totalPrice.push(calculatedPrice);
    }
    console.log(totalPrice);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're creating a new array on each loop

Declare your array outside of the loop first:

```
    var totalPrice = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          var productPrice = document.createElement("span");
          productPrice.className = "price";
          productPrice.setAttribute("id", `price-id-${i}`);
          var calculatedPrice = price[i] * quantities[i];
          productPrice.textContent = `R$ ${getNumberWithCommas(calculatedPrice)},00`;
          precoTotalDiv.appendChild(productPrice);
          totalPrice.push(calculatedPrice);
          console.log(totalPrice);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the values generated by a for loop inside an array in JavaScript by using the push method of an array. Here's an example:

```
// Initialize an empty array
var result = [];

// Use a for loop to generate values
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // Push the generated value to the array
  result.push(i);
}

// Print the final array
console.log(result);
```

This will output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```